# Setting exit code in Python when an exception is raised

Tags: python, exception, exit-code

```
$ cat e.py
raise Exception
$ python e.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise Exception
Exception
$ echo $?
1
```

I would like to change this exit code from 1 to 3 while still dumping the full stack trace. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Looks like `1` the default return code value python uses upon an unhandled exception bubbling all the way to the top? I wonder if it varies by exception type.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Take a look at the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module. You could do the following:

```
import sys, traceback

try:
  raise Exception()
except:
  traceback.print_exc()
  sys.exit(3)
```

This will write traceback to standard error and exit with code 3.

Comment: But ain't there a way to install such a handler without having to open a `try`/`except` clause?  I'd prefer to just call something once, maybe by importing a specific module, and then each raising of `ExceptionWhichCausesExitCode3()` should exit the program with exit code 3.