# Setting an exit code for a custom exception in python

Tags: python, exception, raise

I'm using custom exceptions to differ my exceptions from Python's default exceptions.

Is there a way to define a custom exit code when I raise the exception?

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def do_something_bad():
    raise MyException('This is a custom exception')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        do_something_bad()
    except:
        print('Oops')  # Do some exception handling
        raise
```

In this code, the main function runs a few functions in a try code.
After I catch an exception I want to re-raise it to preserve the traceback stack.

The problem is that 'raise' always exits 1.
I want to exit the script with a custom exit code (for my custom exception), and exit 1 in any other case.

I've looked at this solution but it's not what I'm looking for:
[Setting exit code in Python when an exception is raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720119/setting-exit-code-in-python-when-an-exception-is-raised)

This solution forces me to check in every script I use whether the exception is a default or a custom one.

I want my custom exception to be able to tell the raise function what exit code to use.

Comment: I agree completely.  The old Q you pointed at suffers from solving the issue by having to encapsulate your whole program in a `try`/`except` clause.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can override `sys.excepthook` to do what you want yourself:

```
import sys

class ExitCodeException(Exception):
  "base class for all exceptions which shall set the exit code"
  def getExitCode(self):
    "meant to be overridden in subclass"
    return 3

def handleUncaughtException(exctype, value, trace):
  oldHook(exctype, value, trace)
  if isinstance(value, ExitCodeException):
    sys.exit(value.getExitCode())

sys.excepthook, oldHook = handleUncaughtException, sys.excepthook
```

This way you can put this code in a special module which all your code just needs to import.

Comment: Thanks. I preferred wrapping my code in a try block rather than overriding `sys.excepthook`, but it's still a nice solution.

Comment: Of course; I was under the impression that this question was about the cases in which no try/except idiom was catching the exception. (Or, as in the question stated itself, if the except-block re-raises the caught exception.)

Comment: And: wow.  an accept of my answer 360 days after the answer was given.  That should give me a special badge (long fuse or something) ;-)